# Zoom Webinars: How to restrict access?

Tags: video-streaming

I am about to stream some live webinars on zoom.
I will provide users with a link.

I want to restrict the access to specific users and avoid the invited people to forward or extend the invitation to others. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Note that questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. I've edited the question to remove this part.

Comment: Zoom already has a help page on this (https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115002542483-Restrict-Access-to-Join-a-Meeting?mobile_site=true) and it seems it doesn't support that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on existing documentation, **no, you can't restrict a Zoom meeting to specific users** (*caveat: the site administrator of a Zoom enterprise license might do so, by controlling the login system, but this is far beyond what the asker is looking for*).

- [How to Keep Uninvited Guests Out of Your Zoom Event](https://blog.zoom.us/keep-uninvited-guests-out-of-your-zoom-event/)
- [Access restriction to join the meeting in Zoom app](https://onlinezoomappdownload.com/administrator-access-restriction-to-join-the-meeting-in-zoom-app/)
- [Restricting logins for the Zoom client](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360041019151-Restricting-logins-for-the-Zoom-Client-) (site admin)

Your best bet is:

- limit sharing by sending the URL just before the event.
- use the waiting room to review attendees.
- consider using a different meeting system.

Comment: For a meeting with just a few attendees, the waiting room option is simplest. For a larger meeting, it's a good idea to assign "backstage" duties to a colleague or trusted attendee, make them a co-host as soon as the meeting starts and let them monitor the waiting room, admitting people or not as need be.